# positioning in swift ios sprite kit

Tags: ios, swift, position, sprite-kit

Hi I always confuse like how do people know what is the position of their sprite?

One of the common code I always find is

```
moneyBackground.position = CGPoint(x: size.width - moneyBackground.size.width/2 - 10, y: size.height - moneyBackground.size.height/2 - 13)
```

how can they know that it needs to be subtract by 10 or 13
and why they always use the size of the screen subtract the sprite but divided by two?
what is their purpose?
could someone explain it to me please

Comment: if the sprite has an anchor point of `0.5, 0.5` (middle) then placing it at the screen's size minus half of the sprite's position will make the sprite's far edge touch the far edge of the screen. 10 and 13 are just [magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) which are usually found by trial and error. In this case they will position the sprite a small distance away from the scene edge.

Comment: well, if you design a game and find a node is 10 px off from where you want it to be, you just add/subtract that offset. Basically the answer is: you just know when you need to do it. There is nothing mysterious about it.